# archetypes.referencebrowser widget: new added elements are not sortable with already existing ones

Tags: plone, archetypes

We have a strange behaviour and I wondered if it was by design or a bug?

When activating "allow_sorting=1" on the widget, if you edit your content, add some elements in the widget (related items), these elements are sortable correctly.  Then save and edit again, add one or more new elements, then these new elements are not sortable with already added ones.  But if you add several new elements, these elements are sortable between themselves, but not with already added ones, there are "2" lists of elements.  While saving then editing, every elements are correctly sortable.  Is this a bug or by design?  I think it is a bug and I would like to correct it but I wanted to be sure and eventually someone to test that this behaviour is happening for him too.

Configuring a widget like the "multiRef" field here: https://github.com/gbastien/archetypes.referencebrowserwidget/blob/master/src/archetypes/referencebrowserwidget/demo.py will show the bug (I made a pull request for theses changes to demo.py).

Comment: I'd say it is probably a bug, but I am not familiar with the widget.

Comment: What version of plone? I vaguely remember this problem and it being fixed.